# How to convert big dataframe columns to lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe need to convert lists by column. There is two methods can't meet the requirement.

1. dataFrame.values(), this method convert to list by row.
2. dataFrame['headname'], I have big dataFrame and there is many columns, it is 
   inefficient.

so, is there any method can do it?
I have fake code, it cant run.

```
dataSpectrum = pd.read_excel(DataDir, sheetname=r'xxxx.xlsx')

for i in range(dataSpectrum.iloc[0,:].count()):

    y = dataSpectrum.iloc[1:,i]
    l[i] = y.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking to create a list of lists from the *transposition* of the original.

```
data = dataSpectrum.T.values.tolist()
```

---

```
df  

    A   B   C   D   E
0   9   5  16   4   1
1   7   2  16  30  13
2   7   5   3   2  16
3   5  15  11  23   5
4   3   1   1   4   6
5   3  14   4   0  14
6   5   1  10  21   5
7   9  17  11  10   8
8   6  11  20   6   6
9  21   4   3   4   9


df.T

    0   1   2   3  4   5   6   7   8   9
A   9   7   7   5  3   3   5   9   6  21
B   5   2   5  15  1  14   1  17  11   4
C  16  16   3  11  1   4  10  11  20   3
D   4  30   2  23  4   0  21  10   6   4
E   1  13  16   5  6  14   5   8   6   9


data = df.T.values.tolist()
data

[[9, 7, 7, 5, 3, 3, 5, 9, 6, 21],
 [5, 2, 5, 15, 1, 14, 1, 17, 11, 4],
 [16, 16, 3, 11, 1, 4, 10, 11, 20, 3],
 [4, 30, 2, 23, 4, 0, 21, 10, 6, 4],
 [1, 13, 16, 5, 6, 14, 5, 8, 6, 9]]
```

You could also call `.values` first and then transpose.

```
data = dataSpectrum.values.T.tolist()
```

Which gives you the same thing.

Also, a minor nitpick -

- You can iterate over `df.columns`, which I'd recommend over `df.iloc[0, :].count()`.

  ```
  for c in df.columns:
      df[c].tolist()
  ```